# I want to sum specific cell values by searching for similar values in textbox in c# .net

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I'd like to sum  the column "Total Stock" for similar values of the column "Part Description" and show the result in a DataGridView i.e. if "Part Description" value equals "Head" total stock value will be the sum of all records with the same description:

[image: Description and Total Stock]

Here is what I tried so far:

```
int sum=0;

for (int A = 0; A < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; ++A)
{
    sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView2.Rows[A].Cells["totalstockDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString());
}

txttotalstock.Text = sum.ToString();
```

And this is the query and the code to bind the data to the grid:

```
SqlCommand cmdshowdata = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT 
  [SN] 
  ,[partnum] as [Part Number]
  ,[partdesc] as [Part Description]
  ,[partmodel] as [Part Model]
  ,[stockin] as [Stock IN]
  ,[dateofstockin] as [Date of StockIN]
  FROM [startfresh].[dbo].[Tbl_SpareParts]", conn);

SqlDataAdapter sda233 = new SqlDataAdapter();
sda233.SelectCommand = cmdshowdata;
DataTable datatbldata = new DataTable();
sda233.Fill(datatbldata);
BindingSource binddatasource = new BindingSource();

binddatasource.DataSource = datatbldata;
dataGridView1.DataSource = binddatasource;
sda233.Update(datatbldata);
this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false
this.dataGridView1.Columns[1].Visible = false;
this.dataGridView1.Columns[2].Visible = false;
this.dataGridView1.Columns[3].Visible = false;
this.dataGridView1.Columns[4].Visible = false;
this.dataGridView1.Columns[5].Visible = false;
this.dataGridView1.Columns[6].Visible = false;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Some sort of loop, should be sufficient to solve your problem, have you tried that?

Comment: I have tried above code by making another datagridview and binding it with the datatable. Still cannot sum those values

Comment: Can you show  how you load the data into the row? I think you could do this before binding.

Comment: I load data by above code btw this.dataGridView1.Columns[6].Visible = false; This column is already removed

Comment: *Don't* try to do that by reading the grid's values. Read the DataTable's values. Or write a SQL statement that actually returns the values you want. It will be a lot faster

Comment: A DataTable can have computed columns whose value is calculated by the [Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) property. You can also calculate aggregates with the [Compute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method

Comment: I`m sorry. I`m newbie. Can you show me example? String result = String.Format("{0} + {1} = {2}",
                         /  A, B, A + B);
          result = txttotalstock.Text; where A & B is datagridview rows and columns defined ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a group in your query to include the calculated column:

```
SELECT s.SN, s.partnum AS [Part Number], 
    s.partdesc AS [Part Description], s.partmodel AS [Part Model], 
         s.stockin as [Stock IN], dateofstockin AS [Date of StockIN], 
    (SELECT SUM(stockin)
       FROM Tbl_SpareParts 
          GROUP BY partdesc 
            HAVING partdesc=s.partdesc) AS [Total Stock] 
    FROM Tbl_SpareParts AS s
```

Then you can just display it in your grid.

Comment: Sorry, I have one more question. I tried your code. Works perfectly fine but it does not add that sum values in my sql datatable which is "Tbl_SpareParts" column name "totalstock"

Comment: Is there anyway to join Insert query and your sum query?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, any reason you want to do it at the same time? I wouldn't do it like that. Use that query for visualization and a different one for insert. 

But keep in mind that if you insert the value it will not be updated when you add new records. Perhaps what you need is a database view. Assuming you are using SqlServer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/views

Comment: Yes I`m using sql server(2014). The reason I want sum values of respective parts in my datatable, is to take that "total stock" value of "Tbl_SpareParts" then use that to minus datatable of "Tbl_StockOut" column "total stock". Then in another form i want to balance final stock and export in excel. I have already exported to excel. The only thing now left, is to minus the total stock(sum values of respective parts of stockin) from totalstockout from table "Tbl_Stock0ut"

Comment: or is there a way to not create that totalstock of stockin column, use only it for a view then take that sum data temporarly and minus from totalstock out sum values?

Comment: I read about views, there is a topic "Modify data through view" but I am not that familiar with aggregate functions and their uses. I think we again have to use aggregate sql subtraction.